# Is the reason that each structure have different types explainable?

Tags: c, struct, memory-layout

For example pointer to different types can't be directly converted one another because of possible alignment (maybe not totally correct statement but you don't got my idea anyway). Is there similar technical reason that you can't do something like this:

```
struct A
{
    int a, b;
} ;

struct B
{
    int a, b;
} ;

void func(struct A a, struct B b)
{
    a = b;
}
```

Now delete me and edit this question if you understand it (in some weird case) and translate it to the public.

Comment: Consider to types - apples and oranges. Are they the same? Both could be defined in terms of juice content and volume. i.e. two values. But would you compare them?

Comment: A decision was made to base the comparison on structure name (tag), not on structure.  This works to your advantage in the long run.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How exactly?

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof a == sizeof b); memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof a);`

Comment: Re. your edit: you can write `typedef struct { int a, b; } A, B;` and then you can indeed write `void func(A a, B b) { a = b; }`  . The language feature you are asking for already exists.  You can use `typedef` if you don't want the names to matter, and you can make two different structs if you do want the names to matter.

Comment: My question is for the reason. Firstly I thought it could be possible different  alignment and I asked this question. Now I see that this is not the reason - it's simply a design choice am I right?

Comment: It's called "having a type system", not any technical reason.

Comment: If we would have that argument I would replay with a single word "typedef". But I mainly wanted to know if it's actually a technical reason because I've heard a lot about C strange things (like possible different alignment for pointers). And not only technical but also what does the standard says.

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question either. The answer to the title is "every time":`struct A` is a different type to `struct B`. (That's what the standard says, too). But then your text  asks a range of vague questions that can be summed up as "why are two structs with the same members not the same type?"

Comment: I clarified myself that I was talking about memory layout.

Comment: Your title says "In c when can two different structures with the same context really create different types?"  .  `struct A` and `struct B` are different types, even if they have the same memory layout.  And that has nothing at all to do with most of the stuff in your question body about assignment and whatever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105206/discussion-between-fisocpp-and-m-m).

Answer (score 1):

> In c when can two different structures with the same context really create different types?

They always do.  `struct A` and `struct B` are different types.

```
struct A {
    int a, b;
} ;

struct B {
    int a, b;
} ;
```

> Is the reason why this is forbidden purely the fact that it would be too complex for the compiler or is it something else?

It is not too complex for the compiler.  It is preferable to keep them separate.  If there is a need to be the same, code can use `typedef`.

```
typedef struct A foo;
typedef struct A bar;

int main(void) {
  foo1 x;
  bar1 y = x;
  struct B z = x; // does not compile
}
```

Why disallow `struct B z = x;`?  That is the language design.  If prevents foolish code like below.  Even though `struct JustLikeFILE` has the same fields as `FILE`, conceptually it is *not* a `FILE`.

```
void f(void) {
  FILE *f = fopen("abc","r");
  struct JustLikeFILE g = *f;  // does not compile
}
```

Comment: What if I typedef `JustLikeFILE`? Why does it works with typedefs and not with structures.

Comment: FISOCPP `typedef struct JustLikeFILE F_type;` creates an alias `F_type` that is the same as `struct JustLikeFILE`.  Not a new type.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard defines 'type compatibility' and for structure types to be compatible, amongst other criteria, they must use the same tag.  You structures use different tags — they are inherently different types.

You can find the sordid details in some complexly worded specifications in the standard:

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type
>
> Two types have *compatible type* if their types are the same. Additional rules for determining whether two types are compatible are described in 6.7.2 for type specifiers, in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers, and in 6.7.6 for declarators.<sup>55)</sup> Moreover, two structure, union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible if their tags and members satisfy the following requirements: If one is declared with a tag, the other shall be declared with the same tag. If both are completed anywhere within their respective translation units, then the following additional requirements apply: there shall be a one-to-one correspondence between their members such that each pair of corresponding members are declared with compatible types; if one member of the pair is declared with an alignment specifier, the other is declared with an equivalent alignment specifier; and if one member of the pair is declared with a name, the other is declared with the same name. For two structures, corresponding members shall be declared in the same order. For two structures or unions, corresponding bit-fields shall have the same widths. For two enumerations, corresponding members shall have the same values.
>
> <sup>55)</sup> Two types need not be identical to be compatible.

Since your two sample structures have different tags (`struct A`, `struct B`), they are manifestly not the compatible types.

Your second example uses two anonymous `struct` types:

```
struct { int a, b; } func1();

void func2()
{
    struct { int a, b; } var = func1(); //not allowed
}
```

A different part of the standard applies to this:

> #### 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> ¶8 The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation unit. The struct-declaration-list is a sequence of declarations for the members of the structure or union.

The *struct-declaration-list* that refers to is the part in braces `{` … `}`.  Since you have two of those in a single translation unit, they declare (define) two types, and hence are not compatible.

Your final example, with `typedef int myOrangeInt;` and `typedef int myAppleInt;` illustrates that `typedef` in C does not introduce a new type; it merely introduces a synonym for another type.  In this case, `myOrangeInt` is a synonym for `int`, and so is `myAppleInt`, and since they're synonyms for the same type, the types are the same type.

> #### §6.7.8 Type definitions
>
> ¶3 … A `typedef` declaration does not introduce a new type, only a synonym for the type so specified. …